# How can i visible/invisible the virtual keyboard in FireMonkey app manually?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

for develop video game purpose, recently i am trying to write a **DirectUI** component library using Delphi based on FMX, by now i have got Button、Label、CheckBox done, and they seems perfect when the demo running.
But, when i write the Edit/Memo control, and set it focused, i want to make the virtual keyboard visible manually, so i write following codes:

```
procedure ShowHideVirtualKeyboard(const AControl: TFmxObject; Show: Boolean);
var
  Svc: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, Svc) then
  begin
    if Show then
      Svc.ShowVirtualKeyboard(AControl)
    else
      Svc.HideVirtualKeyboard;
  end;
end;
```

It do works on Windows, but failed on Android. i looked through FMX soure code, and find that the control must be derived from TControl.
So, if my conponents are derived from TInterfacedObject(that is: TDxBaseControl = class(TInterfacedObject)), is it possible to make the virtual keyboard visible manually?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you need just to solve the inheritence problem, then use the composition based `Adapter design pattern`. You can imagine that like one kind of wrapper. Then the container class could inherit from `TControl` and the contained one from `TInterfacedObject`. The container (wrapper) could delegate its calls to the contained interface.

```
IMyInterface = interface
  ['{5360279B-4E38-4844-BD46-234CDC873D8C}']
  procedure foo( x_ : integer );
end;

TMyInterfaceImpl = class ( TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface )
  public
    procedure foo( x_ : integer );
end;

TMyInterfaceAdapter = class ( TControl )
  private
    // Fields
    fMyInterface : IMyInterface;

  public
    constructor Create( owner_ : TComponent; myInterface_ : IMyInterface );

    procedure foo( x_ : integer );

end;


procedure TMyInterfaceImpl.foo( x_ : integer );
begin
  //...
end;

constructor TMyComponentAdapter.Create( owner_ : TComponent; myInterface_ : IMyInterface );
begin
  if ( myInterface_ <> NIL ) then
  begin
    inherited Create( owner_ );
    fMyInterface := myInterface_;
  end else
    raise Exception.Create( 'Invalid input parameter value! (myInterface_)' );
end

procedure TMyComponentAdapter.foo( x_ : integer );
begin
  fMyInterface.foo( x_ );
end;
```

When you need the interface as a TControl descendant, just use the adapter:

```
TForm1 = class ( TForm )
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    fMyInterfaceAdapter : TMyInterfaceAdapter;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender : TObject);
begin
  fMyInterfaceAdapter := TMyInterfaceAdapter.Create( owner, TMyInterfaceImpl.Create );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fMyInterfaceAdapter.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...
  fMyInterfaceAdapter.foo( 5 );
  //...
end;
```